# HTTPS requests sent with ASIHTTPRequest return a NULL response

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, https, asihttprequest

I am developing an iPad application and using the ASIHTTPRequest library (https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request) to make requests to my web server, which runs CentOS 6.2 and is equipped with Apache 2.2 and mod_ssl enabled.

When I make an HTTPS request to the server, sometimes I get a null response. Absolutely nothing. As if the server were completely dead. Sometimes it works just fine, returning the expected response. There is no rhyme or reason to when the response is null and when it's fine.

- The server uses a dummy security certificate
- I am setting validatesSecurityCertificate to NO
- I am setting SSLVerifyClient to none in httpd.conf

Note, HTTPS requests sent through a web browser work fine (after you tell it to proceed without a security certificate). But, all HTTPS requests sent through HTTP Client: ((Zero-length response returned from the server.))

Answer (score 0):

The trick to using ASIHTTPRequest well is that you dont use it. Its deprecated by its author [allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest) . I suggest using AFNetworking, RESTKit or even NSURLConnection.

As it is we have no code of yours to see, but when experiencing random issues with a library that hasn't been worked on in years I would say to start by using a different library.

Comment: It turns out that ASIHTTPSRequest had a default timeout of 10 seconds set. Some of our requests were taking an unusually long time and ASI just gave up at that point.